# JavaScript ~ I need to disable 2 checkboxes when the 3rd checkbox is selected

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I need checkBox 3 to disable checkBox 1 & 2 when it is selected.
The code works when I have the `onClick` in the 3rd checkbox tag, but my lead programmer wants the `onClick` in the JavaScript code above. I'm not that good with JS so I don't know exactly why it's not working. This is what I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<meta name="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript">
<meta name="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
<title>Example</title>

<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">
<!--

var field = document.getElementById("check_1157");
if (field)
{
  function update1157Box(contactMethod)
  {
    var contactMethod = document.getElementById("check_1157");

    if(contactMethod.check_1157.checked)
    {
      //enable the not to receive information
      contactMethod.check_1156.disabled =true;
      contactMethod.check_1156.checked = false;
      contactMethod.check_1158.disabled =true;
      contactMethod.check_1158.checked = false;
      return;
    }
  }

  field.onClick = update1157Box(this.form)

  //the not to receive information
  contactMethod.check_1156.checked = false;
  contactMethod.check_1156.disabled = false;
  contactMethod.check_1158.checked = false;
  contactMethod.check_1158.disabled = false;
}

//-->
</SCRIPT>

</head>
<body>

<form>
  <div class="many-from-many">
    <label style="display: block;"><input id="check_1156"
     name="answers[166][]" value="1156" type="checkbox">Check Box 1</label>
    <label style="display: block;"><input id="check_1158"
     name="answers[166][]" value="1158" type="checkbox"> Check Box 2</label>
    <label style="display: block;"><input id="check_1157"
     name="answers[166][]" value="1157" type="checkbox">Check Box 3</label>
  </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If clicking checkbox 3 disables 1 and 2, how do you change your mind and select 1 or 2?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery makes event handlers a piece of cake:

```
$('#check_1157').click(function() {
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        $('#check_1156, #check_1158').prop({
            checked: false,
            disabled: true
        });
    } else {
        $('#check_1156, #check_1158').prop({disabled: false});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As Eric's solution is using jQuery, here is a pure JavaScript alternative:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<meta name="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript">
<meta name="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
<title>Example</title>

<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">
<!--

var toggle_list = ['check_1156', 'check_1158'];


function toggle(checkbox) {
    if (checkbox.disabled) {
        checkbox.removeAttribute('disabled');
    } else {
        checkbox.setAttribute('disabled', true);
    }
}

function toggleActivation() {
    for (var i=0; i<toggle_list.length; i++) {
        var id = toggle_list[i];
        var checkbox = document.getElementById(id);
        toggle(checkbox);
    }
}

//-->
</SCRIPT>

</head>
<body>

<form>
  <div class="many-from-many">
    <label style="display: block;"><input id="check_1156"
     name="answers[166][]" value="1156" type="checkbox">Check Box 1</label>
    <label style="display: block;"><input id="check_1158"
     name="answers[166][]" value="1158" type="checkbox"> Check Box 2</label>
    <label style="display: block;"><input id="check_1157"
     name="answers[166][]" value="1157" type="checkbox" onchange="toggleActivation()">Check Box 3</label>
  </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This might not be IE safe as I am currently running Linux. If it doesn't work in IE, the problem will be inside the toggle function.

Comment: your answer is good, you just need to change the event handler from `onchange` to `onclick`

Comment: @david Why? I originally thought `onchange` would also include the space key, but at least in Firefox `onclick` works for both. It seems that it doesn't really make a difference. Why do I need to use `onclick`?

Comment: @david I added the onlick event handler, does it work now? Or will it get executed twice?

Comment: I edited it back so that my code example will work for the most browsers again.

Answer (score 0):

My approach apposed to Fabian's, I would do some thing like this, as you have a `div` around around those block of three checkboxs called many-from-many this will look for the (parent `<lable>`) nodes (parent `<DIV>`) of the third check box and then find the childNodes (checkboxs)

```
<form>
  <div class="many-from-many"><label style="display: block;"><input id="check_1156"name="answers[166][]" value="1156" type="checkbox">Check Box 1</label><label style="display: block;"><input id="check_1158"name="answers[166][]" value="1158" type="checkbox">Check Box 2</label><label style="display: block;"><input id="check_1157"name="answers[166][]" value="1157" type="checkbox" onclick="togTopTwo(this)">Check Box 3</label></div>
</form>
```

.

```
 function togTopTwo(c){
    var mm = c.parentNode.parentNode;
    var xx = mm.firstChild.firstChild;
    var secondOfMany = xx.parentNode.nextSibling.firstChild;

    if(c.checked){
       xx.disabled=true;
       secondOfMany.disabled = true;
   }else{
       xx.disabled=false;
       secondOfMany.disabled =false;
   }

 }
```